# Wrapper component for admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I would like to create a new component that contains `Inputs` and `Fields` from `aor` and use it in `<SimpleForm>` and `<TabbedForm>` as below:

```
const WrapperComp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextFieldLabel muiTheme={muiTheme}>Title Example</TextFieldLabel>,
      <TextInput source="status"/>,
      <TextField source="status"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

```
<SimpleForm>
  <WrapperComp />
</SimpleForm>
```

but I get `Uncaught Error: The TextInput component wasn't called within a redux-form <Field>. Did you decorate it and forget to add the addField prop to your component?`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Field` from redux-form to decorate your AOR inputs and use TextField from AOR and pass `{...props}` as pointed by [kunal pareek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6284861/kunal-pareek)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    LongTextInput,
    ImageField,
    ImageInput,
    TextField
} from 'admin-on-rest';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';


const CustomGroupComp = (props) => (
    <div>
        <TextField source="status" {...props} />
        <Field name="staffComment" component={LongTextInput} label="staffComment" {...props}  />
        <Field name="adminComment" component={LongTextInput}  label="resources.faults.fields.adminComment" {...props} />
        <Field multiple name="fileA" component={ImageInput} accept="image/*">
            <ImageField source="path" title="title"/>
        </Field>
    </div>
);

export default CustomGroupComp;
```

Comment: Interesting. The solution I posted below is working fine on my code. I think this https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/896 might have something to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

AOR SimpleForm works by passing the Redux-Form props into its children components. Since you are wrapping up your component, those props aren't passing down to the components you need. You will need to explicitly do this now. So something like

```
const WrapperComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextFieldLabel {...props} muiTheme={muiTheme}>Title Example</TextFieldLabel>,
      <TextInput {...props} source="status"/>,
      <TextField {...props} source="status"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have also this issue but your solution doesnt work properly. It comes with this error: "the TextInput component wasn't called within a redux-form <Field>"

Comment: try passing addField=true as a prop to the component

Comment: What's your AOR version?

Comment: AOR version 1.3.2

Comment: The latest iterations of AOR have some changes from the one I am using. Above might not work. However try the addField=true as a prop to textInput and see.